# "gem install rails" only installs documentation and not rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to create a rails app as the `rails` command does not execute.

When I go to run `rails -v` I get

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

When I open up my rails gem install at `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rails-6.1.3.2` I see the only file there is `README.md`

I assume other files should be installed as well?

If I run `sudo gem install rails -V` in my command line, it says

```
HEAD https://index.rubygems.org/
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/rails
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actioncable
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actionmailbox
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actionmailer
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actionpack
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actiontext
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actionview
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/actionwebservice
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/activejob
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/activemodel
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/activerecord
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/activeresource
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/activestorage
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/activesupport
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/bundler
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/railties
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/rake
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/sprockets-rails
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/rack
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/rack-test
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/rails-dom-testing
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/rails-html-sanitizer
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/mail
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/concurrent-ruby
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/i18n
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/minitest
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/tzinfo
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/zeitwerk
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/method_source
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/thor
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/builder
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/erubi
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/globalid
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/mime-types
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/mini_mime
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/treetop
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/nio4r
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/websocket-driver
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/websocket-extensions
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/marcel
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/nokogiri
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/mini_portile2
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/racc
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/json
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/loofah
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/mini_portile
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/pkg-config
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/thread_safe
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/crass
200 OK
GET https://index.rubygems.org/info/sprockets
200 OK
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rails-6.1.3.2/README.md
Successfully installed rails-6.1.3.2
Parsing documentation for rails-6.1.3.2
Parsing sources...
100% [ 1/ 1]  README.md
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

The only file getting installed is the readme.

Should I be running a different install command?

I also see `railties` installed, which contains `/railties-6.1.3.2/exe/rails`, and this seems to be the file that should be called when running `rails`. Perhaps I need to add this to the system path? I am using Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

sound like you have installed Ruby on Rails with sudo permissions.
You need to use rbenv or rvm to ensure correct permissions. so you don't have to use sudo

you should be able to run
gem install

on its own.

I'd try a fresh start installing your development environment using this guide.

Maybe start a new admin user account on mac just for your rails development.

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur

Otherwise you'll have to hunt down why its not got the correct folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding rails to system path

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure from which source you have installed your ruby and ruby gems like rvm, rbenv etc. and make sure you have access to these folders that are created while installing the ruby and gems. If not please add the path to ~/.bashrc file then you can get access to gems installed in the path.

Run following command to paste your path to source files

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```